# Neo4j web client fails with large Cypher CREATE query. 144000 lines

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to neo4j and currently attempting to migrate existing data into a neo4j database. I have written a small program to convert current data (in bespoke format) into a large CREATE cypher query for initial population of the database. My first iteration has been to somewhat retain the structuring of the existing object model, i.e Objects become nodes, node type is same as object name in current object model, and the members become properties (member name is property name). This is done for all fundamental types (and strings) and any member objects are thus decomposed in the same way as in the original object model.

This has been fine in terms of performance and 13000+ line CREATE cypher queries have been generated which can be executed throuh the web frontend/client. However the model is not ideal for a graph database, I beleive, since there can be many properties, and instead I would like to deomcompose these 'fundamental' nodes (with members which are fundamental types) into their own node, relating to a more 'abstract' node which represents the more higher level object/class. This means each member is a node with a single (at first, it may grow) property say { value:"42" }, or I could set the node type to the data type (i.e integer). If my understanding is correct this would also allow me to create relationships between the 'members' (since they are nodes and not propeties) allowing a greater freedom when expressing relationships between original members of different objects rather than just relating the parent objects to each other.

The problem is this now generates 144000+ line Cypher queries (and this isn't a large dataset in compraison to others) which the neo4j client seems to bulk at. The code highlighting appears to work in the query input box of the client (i.e it highlights correctly, which I assume implies it parsed it correctly and is valid cypher query), but when I come to run the query, I get the usual browser not responding and then a stack overflow (no punn intended) error. Whats more the neo4j client doesn't exit elegantly and always requires me to force end task and the db is in the 2.5-3GB usage from, what is effectively and small amount of data (144000 lines, approx 2/3 are relationships so at most ~48000 nodes). Yet I read I should be able to deal with millions of nodes and relationships in the milliseconds?

Have tried it with firefox and chrome. I am using the neo4j community edition on windows10. The sdk would initially be used with C# and C++. This research is in its initial stages so I haven't used the sdk yet.

Is this a valid approach, i.e to initially populate to database via a CREATE query?
Also is my approach about decomposing the data into fundamental types a good one? or are there issues which are likely to arise from this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very large Cypher query!!!

You would do much better to populate your database using `LOAD CSV FROM...` and supplying a CSV file containing the data you want to load.

For a detailed explaination, have a look at:

https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

(This page also discusses the batch loader for really large datasets.)

Since you are generating code for the Cypher query I wouldn't imagine you would have too much trouble generating a CSV file.

(As an indication of performance, I have been loading a 1 million record CSV today into Neo4j running on my laptop in under two minutes.)

Comment: Thanks, I was begining to suspect this.